# Как сделать jquery ajax запрос на поддомене?

Tags: jquery, ajax, поддомены, cross-domain

Ajax запрос выполняется на основном домене http://site-ru/ (локальный сервер), но не выполняется на поддомене http://sub.site-ru/

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
alert('111');
$.ajax({
    url: "http://site-ru/actions.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {},
    success: function() {
        alert('222');
    }
});
```

});

Файл http://site-ru/actions.php - пустой
Как просто выполнить ajax запрос, чтобы на поддомене вывелось сообщение '222'?

Comment: ошибку выдает какую нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

А там доступ открыт?

Если нет попробуй:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo 'Hello!';
?>
```